# Add constraints to lines in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

How would I go about adding a constraint to how much a line can be dragged? I have a stick man and you can drag all his arms and legs, head and back about but I want them to stay the same length as they started off, so you can't stretch them longer or shorter than they should be, just move them up and down, side to side, in a circle etc. I guess i have to do something with the start/end x and y but im not sure how to set a set constraint to it and also still have it be draggable and stay the same length

```
private Line connectLines(Line line, Circle startNode, Circle endNode) {
        line.startXProperty().bind(startNode.centerXProperty().add(startNode.translateXProperty()));
        line.startYProperty().bind(startNode.centerYProperty().add(startNode.translateYProperty()));
        line.endXProperty().bind(endNode.centerXProperty().add(endNode.translateXProperty()));
        line.endYProperty().bind(endNode.centerYProperty().add(endNode.translateYProperty()));

    return line;
}           
       //mouse pressed event
        EventHandler<MouseEvent> mousePressed = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("pressed");
            sceneX = e.getSceneX();
            sceneY = e.getSceneY();
            translateCircleX = ((Circle)(e.getSource())).getTranslateX();
            translateCircleY = ((Circle)(e.getSource())).getTranslateY();
        }
    };


    //mouse dragged event
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseDragged = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("dragged");
                double offsetX = e.getSceneX() - sceneX;
                double offsetY = e.getSceneY() - sceneY;
                double newTranslateCircleX = translateCircleX + offsetX;
                double newTranslateCircleY = translateCircleY + offsetY;
            ((Circle)(e.getSource())).setTranslateX(newTranslateCircleX);
            ((Circle)(e.getSource())).setTranslateY(newTranslateCircleY);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example. This example does not use `Circle.setTranslate#`. It uses `Circle.setCenter#`. It also uses `Math.hypot` to keep track of the `Line` length. If the line length becomes greater than or equal to 100, the change in the shape movements is subtracted.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewDemo2 extends Application
{

    double sceneX, sceneY;

    Circle circle = new Circle(15, Color.RED);
    Circle circle2 = new Circle(15, Color.BLUE);
    Line line = new Line();

    private Line connectLines(Line line, Circle startNode, Circle endNode)
    {
        line.startXProperty().bind(startNode.centerXProperty());
        line.startYProperty().bind(startNode.centerYProperty());
        line.endXProperty().bind(endNode.centerXProperty());
        line.endYProperty().bind(endNode.centerYProperty());

        return line;
    }
    //mouse pressed event
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> mousePressed = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("pressed");

            sceneX = e.getSceneX();
            sceneY = e.getSceneY();

            Circle tempCircle = ((Circle) e.getSource());
            tempCircle.toFront();
        }
    };

    //mouse dragged event
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseDragged = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println(Math.hypot(line.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth(), line.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()));

            System.out.println("dragged");
            double offSetX = e.getSceneX() - sceneX;
            double offSetY = e.getSceneY() - sceneY;

            Circle tempCircle = ((Circle) (e.getSource()));
            tempCircle.setCenterX(tempCircle.getCenterX() + offSetX);
            tempCircle.setCenterY(tempCircle.getCenterY() + offSetY);

            if (Math.hypot(line.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth(), line.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()) >= 100) {
                tempCircle.setCenterX(tempCircle.getCenterX() - offSetX);
                tempCircle.setCenterY(tempCircle.getCenterY() - offSetY);
            }

            sceneX = e.getSceneX();
            sceneY = e.getSceneY();
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {

        circle.setOnMouseDragged(mouseDragged);
        circle2.setOnMouseDragged(mouseDragged);

        Line returnLine = connectLines(line, circle, circle2);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(new Pane(circle, circle2, returnLine));

        stage.setTitle("TableView (o7planning.org)");

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```